# Getting User and Kernel time of a Thread

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, time, filetime

Here i need total time of a thread,so i am using GetThreadTimes function
to get thread times kernel mode as well as in user mode.

```
GetThreadTimes(threadHandle, &ftCreate, &ftExit, &ftKernel, &ftUser);
LARGE_INTEGER qwKernel, qwUser;
qwKernel.HighPart = ((ftKernel.dwHighDateTime));
qwKernel.LowPart = ftKernel.dwLowDateTime;
```

I Can able to get the thread creation time.But i need to get the ( kernel time + user time ) total time used by this thread.

Since kernal and User time that i get from the GetthreadTimes is amount
 of time taken(either in Milliseconds or Seconds) , how to get those times.

I tried below code snippet. But I am getting huge numbers in the corresponding QuadParts.

```
qwUser.HighPart = ftUser.dwHighDateTime;
qwUser.LowPart = ftUser.dwLowDateTime;
cout << "Kernel QuadPart value :" << qwKernel.QuadPart << endl;
cout << "User QuadPart value :" << qwUser.QuadPart << endl;
```

I am getting the Output as :

> Kernel QuadPart value :140716350575597     User QuadPart value :
>   739454089384
>
> Kernel QuadPart value :-2  User QuadPart value : 739510908248

From the above output i get huge numbers. But my thread's total elapsed time is only less than 10 seconds.

Is this the correct way i am getting the Kernel and User time..?

Thanks.

Comment: It's been a long time since I programmed windows. What you are doing looks about right, but I would definitely check the return value from `GetThreadTimes` - if it returns zero, you've got a problem - and of course, if the function didn't succeed, your values out of the function are pretty much "nobody could guess".

Comment: `either in Milliseconds or Seconds` - this time in 1/10000000 part of second. kernel and user time - from begin execute. create and exit in absolute form 1601

Comment: @MatsPetersson The function GetThreadTimes returns a non zero value.

Comment: Then there's something else wrong, which is not apparent from what you have posted, in some way...

Comment: Did you squire the necessary rights? _"A handle to the thread whose timing information is sought. The handle must have the THREAD_QUERY_INFORMATION or THREAD_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION access right."_  source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683237(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @MatsPetersson what you said is correct, The GetThreadTimes function returns the value is 6,that indicates "ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE".Now  this problem is resolved. thanks for your reply.

Comment: Keep in mind that the kernel time for a thread may include tasks that aren't related to your application, e.g., some device driver code runs on whatever thread happens to be active at the time.